# Form submission Trigger to include form data

Tags: google-apps-script

I know people have posed this question before but after searching through the questions on here for quite some time I couldn't find any answers with the actual script. I know what I'm asking is possible, just dont know how to write it. Any help is appreciated!

We are using google forms to accept event requests and currently all data is being stored in a google sheet.

We want to get emailed the ACTUAL form data (from the form or from the sheet, doesnt matter to me) upon submission of a form. Right now I was able to create an email notification (to another team member) using the following script:

function myFunction() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("charlotte@example.com","Donation Request Submission","You Have A New Submission");
}

Can somebody share with me the script/coding that would get this notification to include the ACTUAL data from the form instead of having it just say "you have a new submission"?

Essentially we want to be emailed all the info so we can communicate with the person who submitted the form, and only use/view the spreadsheet for storage of that info.

My form can be found here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XXtxq9N_rSzjbfUxn2twuryJVLSwVL3f6QsCX_Waxqs/viewform

Thanks!

Jordan

Comment: Is this code tied to the submit button?  Can you post where myFunction is called?  [This may be handy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)  as it looks like you'd need to access e.values

Comment: you did not search very well... a search on this tag for "send email on form submission" returns [a lot of results**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dsend+email+on+form+submission) -- please don't ask for ready made code without trying first.

Comment: @ Jymmy - this post is about Google Form Service ,  see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Comment: @Sergeinsas I went through all those results. I honestly know next to nothing about writing apps-scripts or code so I can't really decipher the posts that well. I was able to figure out how to create an email on the form submission HOWEVER I cannot figure out how to code it to include the submission data. Just wondering if anybody had the specific code, as I assume many people want this done as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I get when the form submits:

"You have a new submission."

This is what I want to get when the form submits:

Name: Mike Jones
Email: mike.jones@example.com
Phone: 914-253-xxx
Reason for Event: Social Gathering
Will be charging guests for event: Yes
Preferred date of event: Oct 29th.. if not Oct 22 or Oct 15
What type of party: 3. Hours (Private Party)
Number of guests: 15-25
Start time: 6 pm
Load time: 5;30 pm
Food Options: We are having the event catered, we will coordinate the details

Comment: see answer below, this is a skeleton on which you will be able to build your script. if you have truoble improving it then ask for specific point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it goes in a very basic implementation, you'll have to add some greetings and/or informations to it but it shows the general idea.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var questions = [];
  for(var n in e.namedValues){
    questions.push(n);
  }
  Logger.log('questions = '+questions);
  Logger.log('Timestamp = '+e.namedValues['Timestamp']);
  var message = 'On '+e.namedValues['Timestamp']+', you submitted a form with the following responses:\n\n';
  for(var r = 0 ; r< questions.length-1 ; r++){
    message += questions[r] + ' : '+e.namedValues[questions[r]]+'\n';
  }
  message += '\nThank you';
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'test subject',message);
}
```